# Подскажите как сформировать массив, использую данные полученные при решении примеров ниже

Tags: java

```
    double distance1 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a1[0] - a2[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a1[1] - a2[1], 2)));
    double distance2 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a2[0] - a3[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a2[1] - a3[1], 2)));
    double distance3 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a3[0] - a4[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a3[1] - a4[1], 2)));
    double distance4 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a4[0] - a5[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a4[1] - a5[1], 2)));
    double distance5 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a5[0] - a6[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a5[1] - a6[1], 2)));
    double distance6 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a6[0] - a7[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a6[1] - a7[1], 2)));
    double distance7 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a2[0] - a4[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a2[1] - a4[1], 2)));
    double distance8 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a2[0] - a5[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a2[1] - a5[1], 2)));
    double distance9 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a2[0] - a6[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a2[1] - a6[1], 2)));
    double distance10 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a2[0] - a7[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a2[1] - a7[1], 2)));
    double distance11 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a1[0] - a3[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a1[1] - a3[1], 2)));
    double distance12 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a3[0] - a5[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a3[1] - a5[1], 2)));
    double distance13 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a3[0] - a6[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a3[1] - a6[1], 2)));
    double distance14 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a1[0] - a4[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a1[1] - a4[1], 2)));
    double distance15 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a4[0] - a6[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a4[1] - a6[1], 2)));
    double distance16 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a4[0] - a7[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a4[1] - a7[1], 2)));
    double distance17 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a1[0] - a5[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a1[1] - a5[1], 2)));
    double distance18 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a5[0] - a7[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a5[1] - a7[1], 2)));
    double distance19 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a1[0] - a6[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a1[1] - a6[1], 2)));
    double distance20 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a6[0] - a7[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a6[1] - a7[1], 2)));
    double distance21 = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(a1[0] - a7[0], 2)) + (Math.pow(a1[1] - a7[1], 2)));
```

Comment: `double[] distance = new double[21];`
`distance[0] = ...` и так каждую строку, так все формулы у вас уже написаны

Comment: Пара `a6, a7` повторяется дважды, а пара `a3, a7` не встречается ни разу. Это правильно? Может распишете подробнее, откуда берутся массивы `a`? Возможно у кого-нибудь получится предложить более оптимальное решение.

Answer (score 0):

double[] array = { double1, double2, double3, ... };
Но, конечно лучше объявить массив заранее и вместо double1 использовать double[i] для iй итерации. Кроме того лучше всего оформить это в виде цикла.